# Python/SQLAlchemy: Event Listeners after_flush fires for decimal values, even if the value doesn't change

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is my method:

```
def member_field_change_after_flush(session, flush_context):
    """
    Keep track of MemberField objects changing per-session.
    """
    member_fields = field_changes[session]
    session_member_fields = filter(
        lambda model: isinstance(model, MemberField),
        session.new | session.dirty | session.deleted
    )

    for member_field in session_member_fields:
        for mapper_property in object_mapper(member_field).iterate_properties:
            if isinstance(mapper_property, ColumnProperty):
                attribute_state = inspect(member_field).attrs.get(mapper_property.key)
                history = attribute_state.history
                if history.has_changes():
                    member_fields[member_field.field_id] = {
                        'member_id': member_field.member_id,
                        'old_value': history.deleted[0] if history.deleted else None,
                        'new_value': attribute_state.value,
                        'field_type': member_field.field.ref_field_type.column_key,
                        'account_id': member_field.account_id,
                    }
```

If I change a value in the DB from say `100.2` to `100.2`, `SQLAlchemy` thinks that a value actually changed and logs in the `history.deleted[0]` attribute in the `dict` above.

I'm fairly new to Python, so I am unsure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a value is changed, your event will be fired. However, to check if the value has actually changed, you need to call `session.is_modified(...)`.

Example:

```
for obj in session.dirty:
    # Here, the field might have been set to the same value
    if session.is_modified(obj):
        # Here, the fields value has actually changed
```

I guess the reason why this is implemented in that way is optimization. The [docs say something similar](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html?highlight=is_modified#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.is_modified):

> **is_modified(instance, include_collections=True, passive=True)**
>
> It is in effect a more expensive and accurate version of checking for the given instance in the Session.dirty collection; a full test for each attribute’s net “dirty” status is performed.